# Microsoft Bot Framework on Skype for Business

Tags: botframework, skype-for-business

I am trying to distribute my bot on a Skype for Business network as described [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/skype/skype-for-business-bot-framework/docs/overview?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

While following the procedure, I get this warning:

`PS C:\Users\XXX> New-CsOnlineApplicationEndpoint -ApplicationIdd XXX -Name NameOfTheBot -Uri sip:bot@XXX.com
WARNING: Attention: sip:bot@XXX.com configuration is not complete. In order to complete sip:bot@XXX.com configuration, you must also run corresponding on-premises commands to create the relevant object(s) in your on-premises topology. Please copy and paste the below commands and run them with appropriate admin privileges in your on-premises Skype for Business environment.
WARNING: New-CsHybridApplicationEndpoint -ApplicationId XXX -DisplayName "NameOfTheBot" -SipAddress sip:bot@XXX.com -OU [A_VALID_OU]`

However, this is not a Skype for Business on-premises network.
Anyway, I decided to ignore this warning.

After 2 days of waiting, the bot still does not show on the network. Is there anything I need to do to enable it?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It should take around 24 hours to the bot to appear, so clearly something went wrong. Please review [this](https://blog.thoughtstuff.co.uk/2017/05/how-to-enable-your-bot-framework-bot-on-skype-for-business-and-how-i-finally-got-it-working) step-by-step blog post to check if what you did match what is explained in the blog post.